# VHDL project : create a components and combine to Digital function generator + Create a tester of circuit?

Tags: vhdl

I am a student in a VHDL&Verilog class, so I have assignment in VHDL to build a function generator like shown in the picture [Generator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWL2x.png) with given specifications.

[image]

Also I have a PDF file from the professors with current specifications, from where I started to build the Counter, Negator, FSM automata, Memory and the Multiplexor, but I did them separately.

Now the problem is to combine them togeter in Generator and make a test on it?

But I am stucked, because I have never learned this type programming language.
Have you got experence in VHDL and can anyone help me?

Thank you in advance. I apreciate this.

Comment: Useful search term : "structural VHDL" should give examples.

Comment: Why don't you include an example of how you have tried to connect two entities together, and tell us what error or problem your code produced?

Comment: That's the idea, I have problems to combine them... different entities.

Comment: Here is my VHDL separate entities code [Word doc of my code] (http://www.megafileupload.com/kyNX/V_Grujoski_Proj1.docx). And I can send you also the PDF file of my Project too :)